# get the frame for a UITableView section

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit

how would one get the frame of a whole section in a grouped table view?

I want to isolate a section when editing by setting the table view's bounds to that frame.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will get the rect for a section using `UITableView`'s `-(CGRect)rectForSection:(NSInteger)section;` method.

Comment: does this include the section header? also, is there a way to get the original bounds without having to store it?

Comment: @Tom Fobear - didn't really tried that method yet, and the doc only says it returns a rect for the section. My guess is yes, but you would verify that

Comment: I can verify (even if quite late) that the rect returned by `-rectForSection:` includes the section header.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:` when the table goes into editing mode and `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` when it leaves editing.

This would also require changes to other `dataSource` methods to return appropriate values as if there is only one section when `self.tableView.editing == YES`.

Comment: I might try this, my method doesn't acctually go into "edit" mode though. I have a section with 2 rows, start and end date. When one is selected a DatePicker shows up. still, good information.